# Using Material2 MdAutocomplete component - how to use onselect event

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to use the new autocomplete component for material2 beta.2 
I can get the component and the options menu to render just fine, but I can not figure out how to preform an action once I select an option from the list

```
<md-input-container dividerColor="accent" [mdTooltip]="hint" mdTooltipPosition="above">
     <input mdInput [formControl]="selectedInput" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="text">
</md-input-container>
<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
     <md-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">{{ option }}</md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

My end goal is to populate a variable called selectedItems that is located in my component every time the user chooses a value from the list (can choose multiple times).

I understand it has something to do with the MdAutocompleteTrigger but I can't connect the pieces together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**

There's a better solution:

Using `md-option`'s `onSelectionChange` event:

```html
<md-autocomplete #appSearch="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let app of apps" [value]="app.name" (onSelectionChange)="onAppSelect(app)">
    {{ app.name }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

**OLD**

You can use the `displayWith` for this:

```html
<md-autocomplete
    [displayWith]="displayFnProject.bind(this)"
    #projectsAutoComplete="mdAutocomplete"
>
```

to `bind` the function isn't necessary, but in my example i wanted to access the component itself. :)

```js
  // somethig is selected !!
  displayFnProject(prj: any) {
    console.log('selected', prj);

    this.filteredOptions.next([]); // clear suggestions -> we do not want to show options if we already selected something ! :)
    return prj ? prj.no : ''; // decide here what you want to display in that input-element !
  }
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/gzjx0ZS9wvw49LWY7THx?p=preview

Comment: I think this will work! thanks! will check now. Feels a bit hacky though

Comment: I guess this function isn't design for this purpose, but until now there is no `event` or `output` for a selection.. :) but its not yet finally developed, lets watch its progress.

Comment: Please note - (onSelect) is now (onSelectionChanged) https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/dcc857664c9313694d020845135f1ce63a66f43a

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions, the autocomplete component has an output `optionSelected`.

```
<form>
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Select" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="input">

        <mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="someFn()" #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
                <span>{{option}}</span>
            </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

And to get the value of the input

```
public input: FormControl = new FormControl('');

public someFn(): void {
    const value = this.input.value;
}
```